# before submit and uploadProgress doesnt work in ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

can any one help me in this problem and i try many ways but beforeSubmit and uploadProgrss doesnt work

```
$.ajax({
    url:"include/ajaxPages/admin/insertNewItem.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:new FormData(this),
    processData:false,
    contentType:false,
    beforeSubmit:function(){
        $(this).find(".progress").width("0%");
    },
    uploadProgress:function(event,position,total,complete){
        $(this).find(".progress").animate({
            width: complete+"%"
        },{
            duration:1000 
        })
    },
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        alert("تم الاضافه بنجاح");
        $(".loadingViedo").fadeOut();
        window.location = document.URL;
    }
})
```

Comment: As far as I know, `beforeSubmit` (and probably `uploadProgress`) aren't part of jQuery's ajax method.  You're trying to use handlers that are part of `ajaxForm` - see here -> **http://malsup.com/jquery/form/**

Comment: what is the difference between $.ajax and ajaxform i think ajaxform doesnt have an url option so how to save a file in database in ajax form

Comment: `$.ajax()` is part of jQuery.  `$.ajaxForm()` is a 3rd party plugin.  If you need something offered in ajaxForm then you need to use ajaxForm.

Comment: The form has the Url, in the `action` attribute (or it can do/should do).  The form attributes should tell ajaxForm everything it needs to know.  Just use `$("#formId").ajaxForm()` to send the form with id `formId`.  The samples on the page I linked show you very simple ways to use it.  Give it a try :)

Comment: thank you my friend

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('rName', $('#upload-resource .upload').attr('data-name'));
fd.append('rfile', $('#upload-resource .upload').attr('data-file'));

$.ajax({
            url: 'include/ajaxPages/admin/insertNewItem.php',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function () {  // custom xhr
                myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if (myXhr.upload) { // if upload property exists
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
                        var done = e.position || e.loaded
                        var total = e.totalSize || e.total;
                        var percent = Math.round(done / total * 100);
                        //console.log('xhr progress: ' + percent + '%');

                        $(this).find(".progress").animate({
                        width: percent +"%"
                           },{
                              duration:1000 
                           });
                    }, false);

                    myXhr.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
                        //upload done
                    });


                    $('#upload-resource .cancel').show().click(function () {
                        //cancel upload
                        myXhr.abort();
                    });
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //to do for success result
            }
        });
```

Comment: the same problem friend

Comment: This code is working for me with no issue. Can you tell me what does happen when you run it? Any error or warning in your browser console? Can you log in some parts of the code to where is the problem that doesn't work?